# If a WHERE clause applies to multiple rows, are all rows tested?

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing projects and assignments. Every assignment is linked to one project but projects can have multiple assignments. How can I select all projects that are not archived but whose associated assignments all have a specific status (Paid)? The following yields the expected result because I currently don't have projects with more than one assignment, but would it work if I did?

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects,
     assignments
WHERE projects.id=assignments.project_id
  AND assignments.status='Paid'
  AND projects.archived='N'
```

Comment: No, this will not work. You will get projects that have *at least one* assignment that has been paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM projects p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM assignments a
 WHERE p.id = a.project_id AND a.status <> 'Paid'
)
AND p.archived='N';
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a41c33/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try with LEFT JOIN might you want this

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects LEFT JOIN assignments
ON projects.id=assignments.project_id
WHERE assignments.status='Paid'
  AND projects.archived='N'
```

Comment: No, this will not work. You will get projects that have at least one assignment that has been paid (and you will get the same project more than once).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM projects WHERE projects.archived='N' AND projects.id IN(
SELECT s.id FROM projects p,assignments s WHERE p.id=s.id
AND s.status='Paid');
```

Try this it may works.